# convert datetime in string format and pass it to query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, oracle, ado.net

i have a query where i am passing value in given below format it is working in oracle pl/sql

```
Select ASE_ID  
from ASE_DTLS a 
where TO_CHAR(CRT_ON,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    between '2020-09-01' and '2020-09-23'
```

Above query giving output. but when i am trying to pass it through c# query in given below format it is not returning value.

```
Select ASE_ID  
from ASE_DTLS a 
where TO_CHAR(CRT_ON,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    between :CRT_ON and :CRT_ON";
```

reciving value from post method in fieldval[0] in '01-09-2020 00:00:00' & '23-09-2020 00:00:00' format.

```
command.Parameters.Add(":CRT_ON", fieldval[0].From.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
 command.Parameters.Add(":CRT_ON", fieldval[0].To.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

while reading it through ExecuteReader getting 0 record.
From & To are as defined in c#

```
 public DateTime From { get; set; }
 public DateTime To { get; set; }
```

and CRT_ON in oracle as date.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values, both in .NET and Oracle. *DON'T* pass them as strings to the database. Use date-typed parameters instead. That `TO_CHAR` is a major bug, preventing the database from using indexes

Comment: `command.Parameters.Add(":CRT_ON", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fieldval[0].From;`

Comment: There are other critical bugs too, like using the *same* parameter name twice, both in .NET and the query Doesn't this throw? At best, the query will return the wrong results

Comment: The SQL query should look like `select ... where CRT_ON between :CRT_FROM and :CRT_TO`. In .NET, the parameters should be named `:CRT_FROM` and `:CRT_TO`

Comment: You don't need to convert every parameter to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates both in .NET and Oracle have no format, they are binary values. The query should use parameters with date-related types, not convert the dates to strings, only to convert them back to dates.

The code has other problems too - the same parameter is added twice, with a different value. The query itself is using that single parameter in the `BETWEEN` clause, effectively turning it into an equality check.

The query should be :

```
Select ASE_ID  
from ASE_DTLS a 
where CRT_ON between :CRT_FROM and :CRT_TO
```

The parameters' type  should be `DateTime` :

```
var fld=fieldval[0];
command.Parameters.Add(":CRT_FROM", OracleDbType.Date).Value = fld.From.Date;
command.Parameters.Add(":CRT_TO", OracleDbType.Date).Value = fld.To.Date;
```

[DateTime.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1) returns only the date part of a DateTime value.

This will work as-is if `CRT_ON` is a `date`. If it's a `timestamp`, the query would return rows only up to `:CRT_TO` at 00:00. To return dates on that day, the query would have to change to

```
Select ASE_ID  
from ASE_DTLS a 
where CRT_ON >= :CRT_FROM and CRT_ON < :CRT_TO
```

And `:CRT_TO` should be incremented by one day:

```
var toParam=command.Parameters.Add(":CRT_TO", SqlDbType.DateTime);
toParam.Value = fld.To.Date.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: i tried but getting error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected. and one more thing  in oracle there is only OracleDbType.Date not OracleDbType.DateTime

Comment: Tried what? You'd get such an error only if you used string interpolation instead of parameters. Or passed a string instead of DateTime to the parameter. As for `OracleDbType` - you didn't specify which provider you used. It could be the generic ODBC or OLEDB providers, Oracle's own fat provider, a third-party provider. The correct type may depend on the field too - is it `date` or `timestamps`

Answer (score 0):

You should use date as `date`. Do not convert it to `char`.

```
Select ASE_ID  from ASE_DTLS a where trunc(CRT_ON) between to_date('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2020-09-23','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: That SQL query doesn't use the parameters. If it did, TO_DATE wouldn't be needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos depending on your local settings it could be required (if default date format is different)

Comment: No it's not. Dates are binary values. You're contradicting your own answer. If you don't convert to char, why would you have to convert the parameter value to date?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  '2020-09-01' is a string that either could be converted by oracle using the defult settings or could be converted using `to_date` if the format is different.  I see no contradiction, my friend. Now if `c#` calls the query by setting the parameter value as `date` that's another matter - in that case you indeed don't need `to_date`

Comment: That's the only matter - using the wrong type. If the correct type is used, no conversions are necessary. If `Datetime` isn't used, the answer is wrong no matter what. You'd have to convert the dates to strings in .NET, using the same format as the query or risk either a failed query or getting the wrong results

Comment: @pirkee i tried as you mentioned but getting error ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: @DikshaKumari something must be wrong with the string you are providing to the query. check your parameter values.

Comment: @Plirkee i tried both ways to send parameter ex1-command.Parameters.Add(":ICD_CRT_ON", fieldval[0].From);  and command.Parameters.Add(":ICD_CRT_ON", OracleDbType.Date).Value = fld.From.Date;  but getting same error .                    my query is Select ASE_ID  
from ASE_DTLS a 
where trunc(CRT_ON) 
    between to_date(:CRT_ON,'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date(:CRT_ON,'YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: @DikshaKumari you keep repeating the same mistakes. If you pass DateTime values you don't need to parse anything. `:CRT_ON` is a `date` already, not a string so `to_date` isn't needed

Comment: @DikshaKumari yep Panagiotis is right - if you use `OracleDbType.Date` then you should not use `to_date` in sql. Use something like this:  `Select ASE_ID from ASE_DTLS a where trunc(CRT_ON) between :CRT_ON_FROM and :CRT_ON_TO` (I replaced your `:CRT_ON` with  2 variables `:CRT_ON_FROM` and `:CRT_ON_TO`)